# Why dependency order in POM impacts to bean visibility

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm trying to wire up one component to existing system. To do that I included dependency to my component (`DataFilter`) into main project POM file.

Order 1)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
  <artifactId>DataFilter</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
  <artifactId>CommandHandler</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Such order (only dependencies in POM file; no import calls) cause that system during start pre-instantiate following beans:

- from main app (`blueprint.xml`)

  ```
  [activemq,parser,rawStorage,commandDAO,CommandService,payloadStorage,payloadRetrieval,rawReply,rawRetrieval,template,consumerTemplate,app-context:beanPostProcessor,app-context];
  ```
- from component `DataFilter`

  ```
  [filters,hdop_filter_pass_less_than_4,vdop_filter_pass_less_than_4,speed_filter_pass_less_than_high_speed,event_and_gps_time_diff_less_than_exp_time,fix_type_recomended_to_3dfix,always_pass_when_motion_or_stationary]
  ```
- and don't see the bean `iCommandService` what cause that `rawReply` in main app can not be created

  ```
   Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rawReply' defined in class path resource [OSGI-INF/blueprint/packaging-jar-camel-context-xml.txt]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.company.product.CommandHandler.InitialClass]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'iCommandService' is defined
  ```

When I switch the dependencies to order 2) (`CommandHandler` first)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
  <artifactId>CommandHandler</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>    
<dependency>
  <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
  <artifactId>DataFilter</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Following behaviour appear:

- main app still pre-instantiate beans as above

  ```
  [activemq,parser,rawStorage,commandDAO,CommandService,payloadStorage,payloadRetrieval,rawReply,rawRetrieval,template,consumerTemplate,app-context:beanPostProcessor,app-context]
  ```
- component command handler (which beans wasn't visible in order 1)) pre-instantiate its beans

  [`iCommandService`,`commandDAO`]
- component data filter is not even mentioned during setting up the camel context; no pre-instantiating of data filter beans, no errors about missing beans.
- camel context starts and built routes properly

Additionally

- Command Handler and Data Filter keep its contexts in `Beans.xml`
- Main app in `blueprint.xml` (or `packaging-jar-camel-context-xml.txt` when build as jar, not bundle)
- Data Filer is compilable as `OSGi` bundle
- No autowire is used

The questions are:

- why the dependecies order influance on visibility or not creating beans
- how to set it properly to achive the moment when all beans for all three components are created properly?

Comment: Can you check the versions of your transitive dependencies in commandhandler and datafilter

Comment: They have two commons dependiences - one to org.apache.camel, and second one to internal company package. In both cases the versions are the same.

Comment: is there any change in your deployment like in lib folder different version jar came or something like that when you changed dependency order